# What are we putting on our faces!?! Why don't we have an agency like the FDA approving/monitoring the safety of cosmetics?

Tags: fda, dyes, cosmetics, carcinogens, pesticides

> **"FDA does not approve cosmetics**, although we do approve color additives
>   used in cosmetics. It is the responsibility of cosmetic manufacturers
>   to ensure, before marketing their products, that the products are safe
>   when used as directed in their label or under customary conditions of
>   use."
>   http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/Transparency/Basics/ucm194552.htm

**Sooooo.... who is making sure these cosmetic manufacturers are ensuring the safety of their products? Of course they are gonna cut corners where they can and downplay results..**

We could be putting on all sorts of **carcinogens, chemicals, pesticides, toxins**, etc. and not even know it. *Why isn't the general public more concerned about this?* **Why isn't there an agency to prevent this?**

Comment: It doesn't matter, FDA is just a puppet of the money. If you have enough money FDA will approve it, no matter what. You should investigate yourself about what's inside the things you consume.

Comment: @holyknight If you're going to make claims like that you need to provide substantiation. If you're so sure it's true then you must have reasons for being so sure, so let's see them.

Comment: @CareyGregory i'm not doing your homework this is the internet. You have all the knowledge you want two or three clicks away. 
You can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_the_Food_and_Drug_Administration and dive into the sources.

Comment: @holyknight You might want to learn how this site works before lecturing people.

Comment: that's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmetics sold in China are subject to control by administrative licensing under the “Supervising Rules of Cosmetics Hygiene” regulations published by the Ministry of Health of the People’s Republic of China (MOH) and the “Rules for Acceptance of Application to Cosmetics Administrative License” published by the State Food and Drug Administration (SFDA).

http://www.intertek.com/cosmetics/exporting-to-china/

Comment: Since the OP asked about the FDA, it seems safe to assume the question is specific to the US, so Chinese regulations don't answer the question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Since many cosmetic brands sell their products all over the world, learning how certain cosmetics are regulated outside the US might help the OP.